# jmeter || Facing issue while doing post method for login functionality, can any one suggest the methods to foloow

Tags: jmeter

JMeter || Facing issue while doing post method for login functionality, please suggest the steps.

I am able to hit the said URL, but when I am passing the parameter I am getting the same response as when I am hitting the URL.
so not sure how to do it for login check.

Comment: Is there any parameter other than userid and password in your post request.

Answer (score 0):

Your testing needs to be realistic, it means that you need to represent real users sitting behind real browsers as close as possible. What real users do is:

1. Open login page (usually GET request)
2. Type credentials
3. Click "Login" or "Submit" or whatever button (usually POST request)

JMeter doesn't "type" anything so you don't need point 2, but you might need to have something in-between in case your application uses mandatory dynamic parameters for tracking client state or security reasons.

So:

- Make sure you have [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) added to your Test Plan
- Make sure you simulating first request (open login page) prior to posting something there
- Make sure there are no dynamic parameters you need to work around. If they are - you need to handle them using [PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

See [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) to learn about why it is so important to closely represent real users and what needs to be done to configure JMeter to mimic real browsers behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Dmitri.
I have added HTTP Cookie manager to my test plan already.
And Yes I have first hit the url where login page is there and then iin another step i have set the parameter, for login id and password.